# github-pages won't run locally

Tags: github-pages

When I try and run github-pages (bundle exec jekyll build) it fails with:

```
bundle exec jekyll build
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/runner.rb:365:in `block in require_program': program version required (Commander::Runner::CommandError)
      from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/runner.rb:364:in `each'
      from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/runner.rb:364:in `require_program'
      from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/runner.rb:52:in `run!'
      from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/delegates.rb:7:in `run!'
      from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/import.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/safe_yaml-1.0.3/lib/safe_yaml/load.rb:43:in `<module:SafeYAML>': undefined method `tagged_classes' for Psych:Module (NoMethodError)
      from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/safe_yaml-1.0.3/lib/safe_yaml/load.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
      from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/safe_yaml-1.0.3/lib/safe_yaml.rb:1:in `require'
      from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/safe_yaml-1.0.3/lib/safe_yaml.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
      from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/jekyll-1.5.1/lib/jekyll.rb:21:in `require'
      from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/jekyll-1.5.1/lib/jekyll.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
      from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/jekyll-1.5.1/bin/jekyll:7:in `require'
      from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/jekyll-1.5.1/bin/jekyll:7:in `<top (required)>'
      from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
      from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
      from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
      from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

The Gemfile is:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'github-pages'
gem 'guard-jekyll-plus'
```

Any idea what might be going wrong?  I've installed (bundle install) many times on my Mac.  This is on Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance,

Ian

Comment: Can you please add your `Gemfile`  content to the question?

Comment: Done - thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If it's a Jekyll plugin won't work on GH. Most likely this is the problem. The other thing is, GH Pages build in the environment of ruby 2.1.7, not 2.2.4...

Comment: Try `bundle install` first, if you haven't done that yet. Then `bundle update`.

Comment: I just saw: Jekyll 1.5.1?! Too old! Definitely, run `bundle update`!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured this out with thanks to Virtua Creative, and this post: https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs/issues/154

I needed to uninstall jekyll and github-pages, then reinstall, and after reinstalling I also had to update, so:

```
gem uninstall jekyll
gem uninstall github-pages
bundle install
bundle update
```

Then I found that I had no javascript environment, so I had to modify my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'github-pages'
gem 'therubyracer'
```

And install again

```
bundle install
```

Now it's all good.

Ian

Comment: :) glad to have helped!